# list of test step results in groovy script

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, soapui

I'm trying to figure out a way to get a list of (names) of just the failed test steps, currently the below code is giving me all the names

```
def TestCase = testRunner.getTestCase()
def StepList = TestCase.getTestStepList()
StepList.each
{
    log.info (it.name)
}
```

Now I'm not sure how to move on from here and the get the failed status of each step in that list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the follow approach: Get the assertion status of the testSteps, and then check if the status is FAILED, UNKNOWN or VALID. You can use the follow groovy code to do so:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.Assertable.AssertionStatus

def TestCase = testRunner.getTestCase()
def StepList = TestCase.getTestStepList()
StepList.each{
    // check that testStep has assertionStatus 
    // (for example groovy testSteps hasn't this property since
    // there is no asserts on its)
    if(it.metaClass.hasProperty(it,'assertionStatus')){
        if(it.assertionStatus == AssertionStatus.FAILED){
            log.info "${it.name} FAIL..."
        }else if(it.assertionStatus == AssertionStatus.VALID){
            log.info "${it.name} OK!"
        }else if(it.assertionStatus == AssertionStatus.UNKNOWN){
            log.info "${it.name} UNKNOWN (PROBABLY NOT ALREADY EXECUTED)"
        }
    }
}
```

Take in account that not all testSteps has assertionStatus (like for example groovy testStep, this is why I check the property in the code above).

This code can be used simply in a `groovy testStep` or as a `tear down script` for your testCase.

If you need a different approach to work for all testSteps instead of only for testSteps which has `assertionStatus` properties, you can use the follow code. However note that the first approach advantage is that if you want you can use it as a simply `groovy testStep`, the alternative counterpart is that the follow script can only be used as a `tearDownScript` and can only works correctly with the whole test execution since the `results` are only available at this context:

```
testRunner.results.each{ testStepResult ->
    log.info "${testStepResult.testStep.name} ${testStepResult.status}"
}
```

testStepResult is an instance of [`com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestStepResult` you can take a look at api to get more info.](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestStepResult.html)

Hope this helps,

Comment: Ohhh, you are right - the whole time I've been looking at the test step status when it was actually the assertion status I needed to look at. This helps so much - I will set this as answered as soon as I can play with the code again in the next 24 hours. Thank you

Comment: @MistaWizard nice to help you `:)`, the problem is that you can only get the `testStepResult` when you run the testStep directly using `run` method from the groovy testStep... if you want to do it when all tests are executed I think that this is the easy way `:)`.

Comment: Awesome! I copied/pasted your code into a teardown script and voila :) I now get an "info status" in the script log

Comment: @MistaWizar nice to help you `:)`.

Comment: how about those not having assertionStatus like groovy script?

Comment: @Elaine I updated my answer for your case, hope this fits also your requirements.